# Loading controller specific code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

I added the above tag in my `application.html.erb`, but it seems my js files are not loaded according to controller. When i navigate to localhost:8000/sessions it does not load `sessions.js`

Answer (score 0):

Rails now uses [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` you can require all your of javascript files with "magic comments":

```
//= require_tree .
```

Your javascript can now be inside `app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js` or even  `app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js.coffee` if you want to use coffeescript.

Note that this will require all Javascript files on every page, which is often a desired effect because the client can cache the javascript and thus only has to download it at the first request. For more information read the Rails Guide I linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

You can load controller specific js files as follows

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>`

So that, if you navigate to localhost:8000/sessions it will load sessions.js file. And it is not necessary to add `//= require_tree .` in application.js.